# Header CSS: How do I accomplish this design

Tags: css

I’ve been designing a header in Figma, and I would like that to become live on my website. Can you help me understand what CSS I have to apply to this design:

[Header Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXUD3.png)

It doesn’t have to be perfect, as long as I start to understand how to control the curves, then I can spend time adjusting to my liking. I can create a curve that is equal on both sides, but I haven’t figured out how to make the design above.

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,
Mathias

Comment: Look into using JPEGs _and_ SVG paths, while newer browsers supports SVG paths in CSS, some old browser versions doesn't, thus having a JPEG as a backup can pay off in a large scale. https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: you can also use https://getwaves.io/ for creating wave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a svg path with a linear gradient.

https://getwaves.io/ is very usefull to get a wave svg.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
                <stop offset="5%" stop-color="orange" />
                <stop offset="75%" stop-color="purple" />
                <stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path fill="url('#myGradient')" fill-opacity="1"
            d="M0,128L120,133.3C240,139,480,149,720,138.7C960,128,1200,96,1320,80L1440,64L1440,0L1320,0C1200,0,960,0,720,0C480,0,240,0,120,0L0,0Z">
        </path>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```